# Combine numbers and character by column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 df's:

```
df1 <- data.frame(m = c("m1","m2","m3"), score = c(2,3,3))
df2 <- data.frame(m = c("m3", "m2", "m1"), dosage = c("a", "b", "c"))
```

I want to combine it to be:

```
m1  m2 m3
2c  3b 3a
```

I have tried with paste command but I loose the colnames. 
Should I do this using joins or there is any other efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a `merge` by the 'm' column (if there are common column names, it will pick up that without mentioning it in the `by` argument), then `transform` to create a 'newcolumn' by `paste`ing the 'score' and 'dosage', subset the columns by indexing

```
transform(merge(df1, df2), newcolumn = paste0(score, dosage))[c(1,4)]
```

---

If we need a named `vector`

```
dfN <- merge(df1, df2)
setNames(do.call(paste0, dfN[-1]), dfN[,1])
# m1   m2   m3 
#"2c" "3b" "3a"
```

Comment: Can you please explain the first one?

Comment: @Dr.RichardTennen  Thanks, I added some description.  Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
df1 <- data.frame(m = c("m1","m2","m3"), score = c(2,3,3))
df2 <- data.frame(m = c("m3", "m2", "m1"), dosage = c("a", "b", "c"))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

inner_join(df1, df2, by="m") %>%       # join data
  unite(v,score,dosage, sep = "") %>%  # unite two columns in one column
  spread(m,v)                          # reshape data

#   m1 m2 m3
# 1 2c 3b 3a
```

This assumes all `m` values appear in both datasets. If not, you have to modify the process to match your expexted output. Do you ignore cases that appear in one dataset only? Do you keep them and fill with NAs? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `data.table` and `t`:-

```
df1 <- data.frame(m = c("m1","m2","m3"), score = c(2,3,3))
df2 <- data.frame(m = c("m3", "m2", "m1"), dosage = c("a", "b", "c"))
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
setkey(df2, m)
df <- df2[df1]
df[, dos := paste0(score, dosage)]
df <- df[, c("m", "dos")]
df <- t(df)
df
```

You'll get output as:-

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
m   "m1" "m2" "m3"
dos "2c" "3b" "3a"
```